# Check whether file exists in a particular directory by giving file name at run time and also writing to the file if it exists Java

Tags: java, file-handling

Want to check whether the file exists at a particular path at runtime or not by providing user input and write to it if it already exists and if doesn't it should show the appropriate message like couldn't write.

```
void writeFile(){

    System.out.println("Enter file name to write in");
    str = sc.next();
    File f1 = new File("path",str);
    if(f1.exists()){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            System.out.println("Enter what to write");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            fw.write(str);
            fw.flush();
            System.out.println("Written inside file" + f);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("issue");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need a main(String s..) method to execute your code.